# How to send email on Syntax error or typeError in node / express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Sometimes we are getting Syntax error or typeError on production server , can we have some custom node trigger which run before server crashed ? Like I want to get email on server crashed

```
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of null
```

I was tryng it with

> process.exit

and

> process.beforeExit

but it doesn't work here

Comment: Once server crashes then it is offline, you would need to handle that error and send email, use try catch mechanism. You can also have two servers, one child and other parent. So when the child node process crashes the parent still runs and emails you. But handling the err is a better method. You can generally code, on any error throw, catch and email.

Comment: could you show to me where you call `.trim()` function?